# Messy Representation Encoding example

Tags: algorithms, optimization, heuristics, encoding-scheme

I am currently working through Metaheuristics by El-Ghazali Talbi where he discusses encodings of algorithms.

*"Messy representations: In linear representations of fixed length, the semantics
of the values is tied to its position in the string. In messy representations, the
value associated with a variable is independent of its position. Then, each
element of the representation is a couple composed of the variable and its value.
This encoding may have a variable length. It has been introduced to improve the
efficiency of genetic operators by minimizing their disruption."*

I have been unable to find a example problem where the representation has been used.

- Does anyone know where these representations are commonly used?
- Can someone point me towards a paper or repository with a code
  example?